Microsoft Graph API got `CANCEL; received from peer`
I want to download files from Microsoft 365 Sharepoint through Graph API but got CANCEL; received from peer error.
First of all, I collected IDs of all items through api.
Second, Download the contents of each item through GET /drives/{drive-id}/items/{item-id}/content
However, after a while, I received stream error: stream ID 9177; CANCEL; received from peer:.
I also found that the download is very slow.
The item which downloaded failed would successfully be downloaded on the second day. (with same process and itemID)
But, the same problem occurs on another item.
I also found a weird pattern.
1st day: collect about 10 GB data through api and got the error
2nd day: collect about 5 GB data and got the error
3rd day: collect about 1 GB data and got the error
4th day: collect about 5 GB data and got the error
5th day: collect about 1 GB data and got the error
...
It looks like there's a throttle or block mechanism.
Is there any way to avoid this problem.
We also use the same program to fetch data from different tenants. The program works well and the data we collect is over 200GB.
It seems there's some limitations or rules in Microsoft Graph API.
